# Will repartition by column cause predicate push down?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

If I do repartition dataframe by a specific column like below:

```
val myData = dataFrame.repartition(100,"eventName")
```

Will the perf of the filter query where I am filtering by the repartitioned column be better? e.g.

```
val filteredData =  myData.filter($"eventName"=="event1")
```

i.e. Will the above filter query result in only partitions which contain "event1" being loaded? 
If not, is the perf of the filter query be same as if I had just done `dataFrame.repartition(100)`.

Thanks!

Comment: which version of spark is this? & what  is your observation so far?

Comment: Using 1.6.1 version of Spark. On a sample dataset (~500K rows) I don't see much difference. Before I venture into testing on large datasets, wanted to understand the concept/theory behind this API and what is to be expected. Couldn't find much details in the spark documentation.

Comment: Just about trying the same logic (spark 2.2)

Comment: in my particular test, it messes subsequent transformations by emptying too many partitions.